# Magento 2: The directory generated/metadata doesn't exist - skipping cleanup

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.3.1: The directory generated/metadata doesn't exist - skipping cleanup

When running `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

we see the warning in screen `The directory generated/metadata doesn't exist - skipping cleanup`

As this is a Vanilla install I am asking this question

**question**: what is this error warning related to? and is it something we can prevent? (seems strange to receive warnings when just following the default steps)

Answer (score 3):

When you are running `setup:upgrade` cache, **file system** such as static files and generated files will be cleared. The message which you get states that the **generated/metadata** folder doesn't exist and it is skipping the cleanup process. You no need to worry about this message.

Comment: Why not worry? Is the folder not important?

Comment: During the cleanup process, the folder is empty so he need not worry about it